# Update a value in a row that is related to another row based on a group ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to copy one value of a row to another by using its symbol (group id). Another row is declared with a different language id.

### Example table:

| ID | SYMBOL | IDLANGUAGE | CATEGORIES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | T1 | 0 | ✔ **good**-category1 |
| 1 | T1 | 1 | bad-category1 |
| 2 | T2 | 0 | ✔ **good**-category2 |
| 3 | T2 | 1 | bad-category2 |
| 4 | T3 | 0 | ✔ **good**-category3 |
| 5 | T3 | 1 | bad-category3 |

### What i would expect a query to do:

| ID | SYMBOL | IDLANGUAGE | CATEGORIES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | T1 | 0 | ✔ **good**-category1 |
| 1 | T1 | 1 | ✔ **good**-category1 |
| 2 | T2 | 0 | ✔ **good**-category2 |
| 3 | T2 | 1 | ✔ **good**-category2 |
| 4 | T3 | 0 | ✔ **good**-category3 |
| 5 | T3 | 1 | ✔ **good**-category3 |

What would be the best approach to this problem?

Comment: This is just a requirement listing, there's no question or problem statement here. See the [tour] and [ask]. You're usually expected to make an attempt to research and solve the problem yourself first, and then ask here when you encounter a specific problem with your attempt, showing us what you've tried and where exactly you got stuck. Make sure you provide a [mre] of your issue. We can help you, and you may find if it's simply someone will give you a quick answer, but in general, for future reference this is not a free write-my-code service.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an update join here:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.SYMBOL = t1.SYMBOL
SET t1.CATEGORIES = t2.CATEGORIES
WHERE t2.IDLANGUAGE = 0 AND t1.IDLANGUAGE = 1;
```

This approach is called a *self join*.  For each pair of records having the same symbol, we match the correct category with the incorrect category, and then replace the latter's value with the former.

Comment: Typo: `WHERE` comes after `SET` ... my answer should work now.